# SQLAlchemy Not Creating Tables in Postgres Database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble writing tables to a postgres database using SQLAlchemy ORM and Python scripts.

I know the problem has something to do with incorrect `Session` imports because when I place all the code below into a single file, the script creates the table without trouble.

However, when I break the script up into multiple files (necessary for this project), I receive the error "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "user" does not exist".

I have read many posts here on SO, tried reorganising my files, the function call order, changing from non-scoped to scoped sessions, eliminating and adding Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) in various spots, changed how the sessions are organised and created in `base.py`, as well as other things, but the script still errors and I'm not sure which code sequence is out of order.

The code currently looks like:

`base.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

# SQLAlchemy requires creating an Engine to interact with our database. 
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/testdb', echo=True)

# Create a configured ORM 'Session' factory to get a new Session bound to this engine
#_SessionFactory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Use scoped session
db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        bind=engine,
        autocommit=False,
        autoflush=False
    )
)

# Create a Base class for our classes definitions
Base = declarative_base()
```

`models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    date_last_seen = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))

    def __init__(self, email, name, date_last_seen):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.date_last_seen = date_last_seen
```

`inserts.py`

```
from datetime import date
from base import db_session, engine, Base
from models import User

def init_db():
    # Generate database schema based on our definitions in model.py
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    # Extract a new session from the session factory
    #session = _SessionFactory()

    # Create instance of the User class
    alice = User('alice@throughthelooking.glass', 'Alice', date(1865, 11, 26))

    # Use the current session to persist data
    db_session.add(alice)
    
    # Commit current session to database and close session
    db_session.commit()
    db_session.close()
    print('Initialized the db')

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
```

Thank you for any insight you're able to offer!

Comment: You are using a different `Base` for create_all and where the `User` model is stored. This creates the issue. In `models.py` use `from base import Base` and remove `Base = declarative_base()`

Comment: That's what it was! Thank you @rfkortekaas!